# How to round floor_date() to arbitrary date?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am using `floor_date` to round dates to the weeks:

```
library(lubridate)
floor_date(ymd_hms('2016-08-26 16:27:15'), '7 days')
[1] "2016-08-22 UTC"
```

However, I would like to set a specific date as the beginning of the first week.
For instance, I would like to set `"2016-08-26 UTC"` as first week. As a workaround I was trying to tweak `getOption("lubridate.week.start")`, but I cannot get to change the starting weekday regardless of what I pass:

```
> floor_date(ymd_hms('2016-08-26 16:27:15'), '7 days', week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 1))
[1] "2016-08-22 UTC"
> floor_date(ymd_hms('2016-08-26 16:27:15'), '7 days', week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 7))
[1] "2016-08-22 UTC"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `unit = "week"`. From `?round_date`

> week_start: when unit is weeks specify the reference day; 7 being Sunday.

Example

```
library(lubridate)
lapply(c(1, 5), function(x) floor_date(ymd('2016-08-26'), 'week', week_start = x))
#[[1]]
#[1] "2016-08-22"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "2016-08-26"
```